# How to retrieve Collection items from Internet archive

Tags: web-crawler

Is there an api to retrieve the items of a specific collection (i.e. children collections)?

Example:
The HTML for the collection `movies` can be retrieved from  https://archive.org/details/movies and JSON/meta from https://archive.org/metadata/movies/ . However the JSON payload has no reference to the **child items** of the collection (i.e. the sub-collections  such "`Arts & Music`", "`Community videos`" etc).

I'm trying to build a wrapper around internet archive API. The API information is quite sparse[0][1][2] and incomplete.

Note: please create a 'internet-archive' tag if you have a reputation higher than 1500

[0] http://blog.archive.org/2011/03/31/how-archive-org-items-are-structured/
[1] http://blog.archive.org/developers/

[2] https://archive.org/services/docs/api/index.html

Comment: To get all the metadata, you'll have to create your own URLs.  For example, here's the metadata for game videos: https://archive.org/metadata/gamevideos and the metadata for the TV archives: https://archive.org/metadata/tvarchive

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm not sure what you mean by that. It looks like you still don't get the children of `gamevideos` or `tvarchive` (e.g. cnn , fox news etc https://archive.org/details/tvarchive )

Comment: You are going to have to create a list of archive.org/metadata/* URLs to get all the metadata you're interested in.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. The whole question is how to retrieve children collections programatically (i.e using a JSON API). Your answer is to create a such list of children myself...

Answer (score 7):

After writing this response I realised it's not really an answer to your question because it doesn't return sub-collections but all items instead. I edited my answer slightly to reflect that and I am leaving it up for future reference.

---

I struggled with just listing all items for a collection - I tried using the Simple Lists API but unlike the `library_of_atlantis` example from the [docs](https://archive.org/services/docs/api/simplelists.html#enumerate-all-children-of-a-parent), it wouldn't return any results for another collection I was interested in.

Eventually I got a helpful response from the IA team suggesting to **make an [advanced search](https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php) query** such as this one: [https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=collection:movies&fl[]=identifier&rows=100&page=1&output=json](https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=collection:movies&fl%5B%5D=identifier&rows=100&page=1&output=json).

There might be a better way to find all the sub-collections of the `movies` collection, but if you add the `fl[]=collection` parameter to the query, it will return a list of all the collections each of the items is in. Maybe you could collect the collection names from there?

As for why the Simple Lists API wouldn't work: apparently not all collections are populated by simplelist (while the presence of a `*_simplelists.sqlite` https://archive.org/download/library_of_atlantis seems to indicate that collection indeed uses simplelist).